# How to add extra comment field in dreamveation's v4.0 quick checkout?

Tags: php, android, opencart

I have an opencart website, recently i developed an android app for it and for the checkout i used quick checkout v4.0 by dreamveation.com. but the problem is in the app's checkout the comment field is shown but on pressing the confirm button the comment is not getting updated to the database.

this is the tpl file

```
Please select your prefered slot of delivery.
<div class="select-input form-group">
<select name="comment" class="form-control comment-select" data-refresh="5">
            <option  value="slot1" id="slot1" selected="selected" >Slot 1 : 9:30 am - 12:30 pm</option>
            <option  value="slot2" id="slot2" >Slot 2 : 1:30 pm - 5:30 pm</option>
            <option  value="slot3" id="slot3" >Slot 3 : 6:00 pm - 9:00 pm</option>
</select>
```

and this is how im trying to get it in the **d_quickcheckout.php**

```
$this->session->data['comment'] = $this->request->post['comment'];
        $data['comment'] = $this->session->data['comment'];
```

but it gives me an error saying that there is nothing with index confirm..

Comment: Show your code and the attempt to you have tried so far to achieve your goal.

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen i have added the edited my post and added what i have tried

Comment: what do you mean by **"there is nothing with index confirm"** ?

Comment: and with such a short code snippet. it's really hard to determine what the problem is, please post the full code of both the template and the controller

Comment: No, do not post that.  Dreamvention's extension is commercial software so it would not be ok to post their code on SO.

Comment: @SusanWilliams - It's almost impossible to answer your question without access to the code in question, and since it would be a violation of terms for you to post it here this question can't really be answered as it is.  My advice would be to contact Dreamvention for support.